# Failed SSL handshake with Flash app on Firefox/Linux connecting to Java server

Tags: java, linux, flash, firefox, ssl

I'm getting a "unknown_ca" error in bizarrely specific conditions: the Flash app must be run on Linux and via Firefox.

It connects fine when run from Windows (Chrome/Firefox/IE) or Chrome on Linux.

At first I thought its a cipher problem since every successful connection used a TLS cipher, while Linux-Fox attempted using SSL. However, if I force the server to only accept the specific cipher Linux-Fox was using, everything else can still connect.

The debug info on the Linux-Fox connection just shows this after Server handshake:

```
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 30                                              .0
Thread-11, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Thread-11, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, unknown_ca
%% Invalidated:  [Session-3, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
Thread-11, called closeSocket()
Thread-11, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca
```

Whereas Windows-Fox shows:

```
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 01 06                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 262
0000: 10 00 01 02 01 00 70 BD   39 2A 63 5D 09 9D D8 67  ......p.9*c]...g
0010: 76 15 02 F6 D6 BD B6 68   95 65 C5 39 D8 C8 A2 86  v......h.e.9....
0020: 5B 0C FA 54 66 65 8C 20   EA 5C DE 49 3C CE 25 0C  [..Tfe. .\.I<.%.
0030: DC 39 9A 18 0E 9F C0 E4   38 1D 1B FA 96 CF B0 70  .9......8......p
0040: 1F E0 ED 01 B7 92 93 0C   F0 0B A9 25 0B 92 83 7E  ...........%....
0050: 2C 3F 47 4E 65 C9 60 11   C6 A2 54 68 A4 68 A5 24  ,?GNe.`...Th.h.$
0060: 99 6B 69 09 25 7F 09 E1   4E 1D 5E C0 34 4C 6C C6  .ki.%...N.^.4Ll.
0070: 4A 16 E5 6C 4E 56 57 92   97 ED B5 25 C1 9B F0 10  J..lNVW....%....
0080: 8B D3 5B CD C1 58 CD 1C   F9 E7 85 D8 42 89 53 E6  ..[..X......B.S.
0090: 39 D2 AD A8 C3 C0 17 B9   A1 2E 5C F0 50 80 EB 8C  9.........\.P...
00A0: 31 83 A4 87 14 D3 F8 61   01 92 67 B9 6F B2 3E 7D  1......a..g.o.>.
00B0: DA BE EC 87 9B 2C 19 A5   31 E2 76 5E B8 2D 9B 66  .....,..1.v^.-.f
00C0: 9E E1 12 6F CC A7 B9 3B   E1 5D B0 75 A2 47 64 92  ...o...;.].u.Gd.
00D0: 56 4D C4 CD F5 A3 79 F4   89 58 6F 61 5E 74 89 F5  VM....y..Xoa^t..
00E0: FE 9B 79 D4 E2 3D 02 2E   FD A8 8D 7C 25 D4 A4 41  ..y..=......%..A
00F0: 87 7D B3 96 AA C4 B6 00   7F 3A 99 64 C6 A1 FD F6  .........:.d....
0100: 8C 66 E5 D1 F3 5C                                  .f...\
```

Is that ".0" an error code that indicates something wrong on Flash side? Is there some way I can get detailed debug info from Flash?